# Written notation for voltage divider

Tags: circuit-analysis, circuit-design

Is there a notation for the expression of a voltage divider? What I mean with this is some notation to express \$Z_1/(Z_1+Z_2)\$, like the notation Z1//Z2 for the expression of parallel impedances \$Z_1*Z_2/(Z_1+Z_2)\$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a notation for the expression of a voltage divider?

Short answer:  No.

Parallel (||) and series (+) resistors have their own notation because they are the most fundamental ways of combining resistors.  AND, the result is a resistance value.  The result of an attenuator is an attenuation factor in % or dB or whatever.  The expression for an attenuator is not simply a simplification that takes in one unit and returns the same unit.  The variation in the units of the result make it impossible for one notation to cover all possible uses.

Update:

Let me expand.  For both a parallel (R1||R2) and serial (R1+R2) expression. there is no ambiguity.  Both R1 and R2 are in ohms, and the result is in ohms; always ohms, nothing else.  this is why the expression, especially the parallel expression, can be substituted into more complex equations.

This is not the case with a 2-resistor voltage divider / attenuator.  Let's assign the symbol & to mean "the voltage divider of", as in R1\R2 equals the voltage divider of R1 and R2, where R1 is the series leg and R2 is the shunt leg.  That's fine, but what is the dimension of the equivalent result?  The Thevenin equivalence of a 2-resistor attenuator is simply the two resistors in parallel, but we already have an expression for that.

If we would normally write:

Vout = Vin x (R2 / (R1 + R2))

then this would turn into:

Vout = Vin x R1\R2

Which I guess could work.  My concern is that because \ is dimensionless, it will not play well with others.  When calculating the transfer function of an active filter, parallel impedances can be reduced to their Thevenin equivalent, that equivalence can be dropped directly into the equations with other component values, and the effects of its real value can be observed.

OTOH, if in the feedback loop of an opamp there is a 2-resistor attenuator along with other components, substituting the equivalent \ value loses critical information, the network impedance of the attenuator relative to the other impedances in the loop.  There is nothing in the equivalence that indicates whether the shunt leg of the attenuator is ohms or megohms.

All of which is to say that not only is there no standard expression for a two-element attenuator, and I can understand one possible reason why not.

Comment: I thought this closer to the right things to say. So +1.

Comment: Observation: the answer is only `no` until someone defines a notation or, maybe one already exists.

Comment: Who says the voltage divider, is not The Thevenin equivalent? @jonk.= ? There is no standard syntax or symbol but that's what it is called as anyone can define whatever symbol they want as long as it is declared,

Comment: Ok, I accepted the answer since it seems there is not notation. However I don't agree with what you said about the units, an attenuation is a "times" factor, there is no unit problem. It is a value with no units. Whether you express in "times", percentage or dB it is the same quantity you are talking about, you are just changing the scale. It is like impedance, which can be expressed in ohm, kilohm, etc

Comment: Updated the answer with examples.

Answer (score 0):

It is called the [Thevenin equivalent circuit](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Th%C3%A9venin%27s_theorem). Zeq, Veq for equivalent values.

Veq= Vin*Zout/(Zin+Zout)
Zeq= Zin//Zout

Where Z or \$Z{(\omega)}= R+j\omega L \text{ or } 1/(j \omega C)\$
and L has DCR while C has ESR added to R if significant, for the simple RC or RL circuit or simply Z=R for the resistor only cct.

Comment: Thank you for answer, I have edited my question since I think it wasn't clear

Comment: It was clear to me already. The only notation is Veq,Req

Comment: \$\textbf{V}_{_\text{TH}}\$ and \$\textbf{Z}_{_\text{TH}}\$ would be just as standard as the names you provide. I think there's no actual standard of the kind the OP is looking for.

Comment: I use \$R_{\text{TH}}\$ for Thermal resistance and \$R_{\text{EQ}}\$ for equivalent or Zeq or Req or s11, s22 wherever convenient as long as it is defined.

Comment: Who says the voltage divider, is not The Thevenin equivalent? @jonk.= ? There is no standard symbolic form but that's what it is called as anyone can define whatever symbol they want as long as it is declared,

Comment: @TonyStewart I think it's fine you use "TH" for thermal.

Answer (score 0):

> *What I mean with this is some notation to express \$Z1/(Z1+Z2)\$*

[\$\color{blue}{\boxed{\text{S21}}}\$](https://www.everythingrf.com/community/what-are-s-parameters) might be what you are looking for. It's called a "scattering" parameter but describes the forward gain (or attenuation) of many things.

- S11 is the input port voltage reflection coefficient
- S12 is the reverse voltage gain
- \$\color{black}{\boxed{\text{S21}}}\$ is the forward voltage gain
- S22 is the output port voltage reflection coefficient

\$\color{black}{\boxed{\text{S11}}}\$ and \$\color{black}{\boxed{\text{S22}}}\$ are the numbers that can represent the input and output impedance relative to some preferred standard value like 50 Ω. They are in decibels and, strictly speaking represent the reflection of power. They are sometimes called return loss.

---

A potential divider can be used within an [impedance matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impedance_parameters): -

[image]

Hence, it is regarded as a 2-port network and, 2-port networks can be converted to S parameters using [this method from wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impedance_parameters#Relation_to_S-parameters). Yes, it's a little convoluted but, at the end of the day, you want a "thing" that represents the gain or attenuation of a potential divider hence, I've demonstrated that a potential divider can be represented by impedance parameters and, these convert to S parameters as per the above link.

Comment: Thank you for answer, I have edited my question since I think it wasn't clear, or maybe you are answering it but I'm not understanding

Comment: What are you not understanding? What do you understand? Forward gain/attenuation is \$Z1/(Z1+Z2)\$.

Comment: S21 is the scattering parameter of a network. I'm not seeing how to use it as notation to express Z1/(Z1+Z2). Are you answering that a possible solution is to define a network composed by Z1 and Z2 and instead of writing Z1/(Z1+Z2) I can use S21?

Comment: Two resistors conjoined to make a potential divider is as valid a 2-port network as anything more complex @MPA95

Answer (score 0):

\$\frac{\textbf{Z}_{_\text{1}} \mid\mid\, \textbf{Z}_{_\text{2}}}{\textbf{Z}_{_\text{2}}}\$ would be another way to express it. So would \$\textbf{G}_{_\text{2}}\left(\textbf{Z}_{_\text{1}} \mid\mid \textbf{Z}_{_\text{2}}\right)\$. Those are just algebraic re-writings.

No one has come up with a widely accepted, stand-alone (no further context required) notation symbol specifically for this purpose that I've become aware of over my many decades of reading.

Comment: you could have also said it was \$\dfrac{Y_2}{Y_1+Y_2}\$ and still avoid the accurate declaration of the Thevenin equivalent resistance or impedance.

Comment: @Tony I could write it a dozen ways and still not have exhausted the possibilities.